# DIY Two Routers on 18650

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, 12v

I wanted to build the following project to have a constant backup source when power outage occurs. I only know very basic electronics, but can solder simple things, willing to learn new things.

**Hardware requirements:**

1. Fibr Modem 12V, 1.5A
2. Wifi Router 12V, 2A

**Idea:**

- Use 18650 Li-ion battery
- A module to control 12V output
- Battery can be charged using solar PV or direct DC 12V

At the moment, I know it can be done, but I am clueless on what else will I need.

[image: prob vs solution]

**Additional Questions:**

1. How many 18650 do I need? considering one battery has 3.2V, multiplied by 4 then result is 12.8V. Is this correct?
2. Assuming 4 is needed to have 12V, I have two routers, how much more can I add? If I add more, it will be more than 12V right? How to manage it?
3. If I wanted it to last for 2hours, how many Ah is needed and how many batteries?
4. Do I need any module or battery-management-system (BMS) to control the 12V constant output?
5. Both has different Ampere, will this be a problem if I need to power them on one backup power source?
6. What do I need aside from the PV to power the 18650? I mean, do I need any BMS?

Hope someone can help shed some light.

Comment: If the power is "out", presumably your internet will also be out, will it not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: To rephrase, do you know that your fiber provider's service stays up through power outages? Because if it doesn't, then this is futile.

Comment: I recommend that instead of using li-ions, you instead use a 12V SLA. You are not constrained by space/weight, and SLA batteries are far more tolerant and easy to charge (no cell balancing needed, less risk of fire, cheaper batteries).

Comment: For this static DIY application a much easier is to use 12V 7Ah (or more) UPS battery. It should be charged to 13.8V and used down to 10-11V. Both devices would work fine with that votage range. A discharge protection relay can be used to manage the battery cutt-off.

Comment: Verizon FIOS works through power outages, if you have the backup battery/UPS. Depends on how severe the storm is though.

Comment: As for the power requirements, ten bucks says both devices don't use 12V directly, they regulate it down internally. You could bypass this by regulating down to the internal voltage required.

Comment: Why not just buy a small UPS?

Comment: Hi there is no fun if you don't DIY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The nominal voltage of these batteries is 3.6 or 3.7 V, and four of them in series should be enough for a buck converter to provide 12V to the router. The charging circuit needs to be balancing. You can buy cheap balancing BMS charger circuit boards of variable quality on Ebay. If the BMS doesn't have a low voltage protection feature, you'll have to implement that separately.
2. You manage an increased current draw by paralleling cells. Instead of four cells in series, you can have groups of two, three, four, as many as you like cells paralleled, and then put four such groups in series. The buck converter needs to be scaled up accordingly, naturally.
3. If both devices pull 3.5A, and you want them to last for 2 hours, you need `3.5A * 2h = 7Ah` of capacity. Parallel cells until you reach this number.
4. Yes, if you use Lithium cells, you need a BMS. Especially if you want your system to charge the cells as well as discharging them.
5. No. The loads will be in parallel, and each load will only draw as much current as it needs at any given time (which is, by the way, probably lower than the rated current most of the time).
6. Yes, you will need some sort of BMS if you want to use Lithium cells, especially when you want to use multiple cells in series.

As others have mention in the comments, you will have an easier time using a deep cycle 12V lead acid battery instead of Lithium. The battery management is much easier with this kind of battery. Using Lithium cells is certainly doable, but if weight or space is not a constraint, it might turn out to be unneccesarily complicated.